# Rails Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to create user defined Rails environment.... By default support development,staging,production,test... Other than that is it possible for user defined environment.... If yes how? ... please suggest me on this ... thanks in advance...

Comment: Do u really knwo the difference between three environment in rails.?
Whats the pupose of that? Why we are using three different environment?

Comment: Hey For development we used our local environment, staging for development server & production for production environment and finally test environment

Comment: and for the records: [railscasts#72](http://railscasts.com/episodes/72-adding-an-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define whatever environments you like by adding a my_awesome_environment.rb file to `config/environments`. After that, if you want to run a rake task in that environment you could do `rake awesome:task RAILS_ENV=my_awesome_environment`.

And, unless it's changed recently, there is no staging environment by default. Only development, test, production. As an example of "custom" environments, [Cucumber](http://cukes.info), has its own cucumber environment when you set it up for a project.

If you have a more specific question, we might be able to give a more specific answer. As it stands, this is pretty open ended.